# Type inference in pattern match over list

Tags: f#

I'm stuck with trying to create a function that will do the following:

```
let p = [1, 2, 4, 2, 1]
let v = 8
```

then I want to go over the elements in `a` until I find the index `i` of the one where all elements up to and including `i` are greater or equal than `v`. So in this case it should return 4, because 1+2+4 < 8 and 1+2+4+2 > 8. So there 4th element, value of 2 puts the total over 8.

(some background: I want to do monte carlo, where I have a list of probabilies that add up to 1. Then I pass a random number between 0 and 1 to have it pick one of the possible future states. Simple example here with ints)

What I have so far is this:

```
let p = [1, 2, 4, 2, 1]

let pick (v:int) (l:int list) = 
    let rec sub (i:int) (acc:int) (l2:int list) =
        match l2 with
        | h::t -> if acc+h >= v then i else sub(i+1, acc+h, t)
        | _ -> failwith "total list didn't amount to " + v
    sub 0 0 l

pick 8 p
```

But it gives the following error on the bit `sub(i+1, acc+h, t)`:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    int -> int list -> int
```

But I'm not passing the function `sub` itself, I'm *calling* it complete with arguments and brackets and all, so why doesn't it return int, the result of the function?

How do I make it return the result of the function?

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you give the 3-tuple `(i+1,acc+h,t)` where curried function is supposted to be:

```
| h::t -> if acc+h >= v then i else sub (i+1) (acc+h) t
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks, had been playing with a lot of combinations except that one.

Answer (score 2):

First, `p` will be understood as `[(1, 2, 4, 2, 1);]` which is an `(int*int*int*int*int) list` with only one element. `p` as an `int list` should be `[1; 2; 4; 2; 1]`.

Second, `sub(i+1, acc+h, t)` in line 6 should be called in the curried form, not in the tuple form. The correction is `sub (i+1) (acc+h) t`.

Comment: Hi thanks, I added that by hand, keeping putting in commas instead of colons